# How to override an external html template angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multi-select

I'm using this https://github.com/amitava82/angular-multiselect multiselect dropdown for my project.

In my html:

```
<am-multiselect class="sv-manage-multiselect-dropdown"
                 ng-model="nameList.name"
                 options="name as name.key for name in nameList"
                 multiple="true"                  
</am-multiselect>
```

This dropdown has a "checkall" and "uncheckall" button in the dropdown, which I WANT to remove, while keeping the functionality of the multi-select.

This is the html in the directive the guy uses:

src/multiselect.tmpl.html

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ng-click="toggleSelect()" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{'error': !valid()}">
        {{header}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="searchText.label" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Filter" />
        </li>
        <li ng-show="multiple" role="presentation" class="">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-xs" ng-click="checkAll()" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Check all</button>
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-xs" ng-click="uncheckAll()" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Uncheck all</button>
        </li>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchText" ng-class="{'selected': $index === selectedIndex}">
            <a ng-click="select(i); focus()">
            <i class='glyphicon' ng-class="{'glyphicon-ok': i.checked, 'empty': !i.checked}"></i> {{i.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wan't to just remove/override the checkall and uncheckall buttons WITHOUT editing this library's directive. I can override the CSS in my personal file.css, but how do I override the HTML template he uses. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 ways you could do it:

1. Add your own template to replace this one like this ([reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)):

   ```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="multiselect.tmpl.html">
     html template without buttons here
   </script>
   ```

   The potential issue with this is that you would be overriding this template everywhere it's used. But maybe you are using this in a bunch of places and that makes sense.
2. Add a decorator to the directive that removes the part of the template you don't want during the compile phase and allows the rest of the directive to perform as usual:

   ```
   decorator('amMultiselectPopupDirective' ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
     var directive = $delegate[0];
     var compile = directive.compile;

     directive.compile = function(tElement, tAttrs) {
       var link = compile.apply(this, arguments);

       if (tAttrs.disableCheckAll) {
         tElement.find('li[ng-show="multiple"]').remove();
         // this code could be different, but the gist is that it would remove or hide the stuff you don't want
       }
       return function() {
         link.apply(this, arguments);
       };
     };
     return $delegate;
   }]);
   ```

   The potential issue here is that you would be changing the template for this directive everywhere the directive is used. That's why in my example I made the template change conditional based on some attribute you could define, like `disableCheckAll`.
3. Use `template-url` attribute that is already defined for this directive and create your own template that doesn't have these buttons:

   ```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="yourowntemplate.html">
     html template without buttons here
   </script>

   <am-multiselect ...
     template-url="yourowntemplate.html">
   </am-multiselect>
   ```

I would say 3 is probably the best way to do it. But 1 could work better if you wanted to override the default, and then you wouldn't have to pass in the `template-url` everytime you use the `am-multiselect` directive.

**Edit:** Here is a working example for 3: http://plnkr.co/edit/m0lZSHUJ8MHslqCNPnCc?p=info

Comment: I did the 3rd way and I get the error: vendor.js:11655 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'amMultiselectPopup' must have exactly one root element. noButtons.html

Comment: @Angular What does your template look like?

Comment: @Angular I updated my answer to show a working example of my 3rd way. I'm not sure exactly what issue you were having since I haven't seen any of your code besides that template.

Comment: It woked without using  type="text/ng-template". I just made a new html and did template-url on the multiselect. Strange but it woked! thanks

Comment: @Angular Yeah, you didn't have to do the `text/ng-template`. A new html file with that name does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Overlap his directive with your own div with class: "no-btns"
2. Add this css:
   .no-btns .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(2) {display:none;}

Example:

```
<style>
  .no-btns .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
<div class="no-btns">
  <am-multiselect class="sv-manage-multiselect-dropdown"
                  ng-model="nameList.name"
                  options="name as name.key for name in nameList"
                  multiple="true"                  
  </am-multiselect>
</div>
```

Comment: in my css i did:

  .no-btn .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(2){
display:none;

  }  

In my html, right above the <am-multiselect, I added div class="no-btn" and closed the </div> below the multi-select. Still didn't work??

Comment: No I'm not allowed to add/edit/change the actual html file in his directive. I want to override it in MY html or MY css

Comment: Shure, just overlap you directive usage .. like this:

<div class class="no-btns"> <untouch></untouch>   </div>

Comment: Can you edit your example with this please? Where do I put this? above my <am-multiselect>?

Comment: Updated, check my answer

Comment: I think I catch. Can you open your page in browser, and copy html starting from  wrapper (with dropdown directive of course)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114386/discussion-between-vitalii-and-angular).